# how to use org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter to correct character encoding?

Tags: spring, hibernate, character-encoding, tomcat6

I need some help.

I placed the code snippet below in my `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and in my `server.xml`:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

My jsp pages are encoded as `UTF-8` and my mysql table is encoded as `utf8_general_ci`.

My problem is that whenever I save a `ñ` it becomes `?`.

When I tried to manually save `ñ` in the mysql terminal its saving properly. I suspect the problem lies within my server or my program. Please help.

Answer (score 25):

I tried successfully with this in `web.xml` !

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks again. I somehow lost the * in the url-mapping and the filter stopped working. Took me a while to spot the missing star. This markup you posted above works perfectly, just make sure you don't remove the star from the url-pattern :-)

Answer (score 8):

To work in spring boot you can use

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

[another response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the following snippet in your jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

and also make sure that the `encodingFilter` is the first filter in `web.xml` file

Comment: I have that in my jsp page and also encodingFilter is the first filter in my web.xml.

Answer (score 4):

My solution, using Spring (3.2.x) AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext, based on Spring Framework Reference:

```
public class StudentApplicationConfig extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext
            = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
    return dispatcherContext;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {

    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext
            = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    return appContext;
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    Filter[] filters;

    CharacterEncodingFilter encFilter;
    HiddenHttpMethodFilter httpMethodFilter = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();

    encFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

    encFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    encFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

    filters = new Filter[] {httpMethodFilter, encFilter};
    return filters;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

it might be little be late, but it´s better to configure it in tomcat conf/web.xml (or for project in web.xml)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding or tomcat´s [web.xml](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/trunk/webapps/host-manager/WEB-INF/web.xml)

Or for jetty like this:

```
public class StartEmbeddedJetty{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler sch = new ServletContextHandler();
    sch.addFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter .class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
      ...
    server.start();
    server.join();
}

public static class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
     @Override
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // set encoding to utf-8
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     }

     @Override
     public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        /* empty */
     }

     @Override
    public void destroy() {
        /* empty */
    }
   }
```

}