# How to configure CharacterEncodingFilter in SpringBoot?

Tags: encoding, spring-boot

I encountered some encoding problems in learning Spring Boot;
I want to add a CharacterEncodingFilter like Spring 3.x.
just like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Just add it as a bean definition to your configuration.

Comment: i have tried to initialize a javax.servlet.Filter,but it not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot

Comment: i solve it with the example.thank u very much!

Comment: It's not working for Spring 4.x. You should use <param-name>forceRequestEncoding</param-name> instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Example code for your Application.java class, as proposed in the comments above:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 73):

Since **Spring Boot 1.4.2** registering your own *CharacterEncodingFilter* will work **ONLY IF** you disable Spring's own instance of this bean by setting `spring.http.encoding.enabled=false` in the *application.properties*.

However, one can resolve this matter without any *Filter* instantiation by adding these setting to the *application.properties*:

```sh
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
# Enable http encoding support.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
# Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
spring.http.encoding.force=true
```

*Source: [Appendix A. Common application properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties)*

Comment: You are right, using properties is the better choice.

Comment: Since spring boot 2.3: The spring.http. properties have been moved to server.servlet.encoding., spring.mvc. and spring.codec., see #18827.

Answer (score 12):

I also prefer `application.properties` configuration. But `spring.http.encoding` is depracted in the new spring boot versions (>2.3). So new application.setting should look like this:

```
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
```

Answer (score -9):

I think there is no need to explicity write the following properties in application.properties file:

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8

spring.http.encoding.enabled=true

spring.http.encoding.force=true

Instead if you go to pom.xml in your application and if you have the following, then spring will do the needful.

[image: Property]