# Hibernate + JPA + jTDS + SQL Server = Unicode Problems

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, unicode

I maintain a piece of software that runs as a Servlet and can make use of MySQL, Oracle or SQL Server as the DB backend - depending on what the Customer wants to use.

Everything works perfectly with **MySQL** and **Oracle**, and SQL Server works great too, except I **cannot insert/update Unicode sequences into the database**.

I can do a manual insert in SQL Server Management Studio of a unicode sequence like this

```
INSERT INTO mytable (msg) VALUES (N'Modern Standard Hindi (मानक हिन्दी), is a standardised and Sanskritised register of the Hindustani language.')
```

This data is output in my software correctly, so this verifies that the database and the web front end can both handle unicode no problem.

And here's my connection string

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server ip>:1433/MyDb
```

As I said, **Oracle** and **MySQL** work perfectly using this setup. What's different about SQL Server?

**Note**: I also tried the official Microsoft-provided JDBC driver with exactly the same results.

If it makes a difference, I'm using [JPA Repositories](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-data-jpa-repository.html) to do my DB interactions. The whole webapp is also set up as a SpringMVC application.

**Edit:** I also tried adding `useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the end of my connection string with the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there was one thing I left off my original question.

I had the system set up with Spring Security and a `CharacterEncodingFilter` in the filter chain to force UTF-8 in all requests and responses, but I had it set up in the `afterSpringSecurityChain` section of my web security initializer.

I moved the filter into the `beforeSpringSecurityChain` method and boom - everything UTF-8 works perfectly with all DB vendors.

I ended up not adding any params to my connection string or anything either. It was literally just the filter that I changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34836332/6460660 this may help by setting the properties

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify in your connection string that you're using Unicode, and also what encoding you're using. Maybe something like this?

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server_ip>:1433;databaseName=MyDb;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I already tried that to no avail. The results are identical. Inserting "فُصْحَى" results in "ÙÙØµÙØ­ÙÙ" being saved in the DB still.

Comment: You added 7 unicode codepoints 0641, 064f, 0635, 0652, 062d, 064e, 0649 (encoded in UTF8 as d981, d98f, d8b5, d992, d8ad,d98e, d989) and got, I surmise, the 14 codepoints 00d9 0081, 00d9, 008f, 00d8, 00b5, 00d9, 0092, 00d8, 00ad, 00d9, 008e, 00d9, 0089 (some of them aren't printable which is why it looks like only 8 characters). In other words, the characters were correctly converted into UTF-8 first, then another bit of software came along and treated each byte of the encoding as an 8-bit ISO 8859-1 character, and converted them into unicode codepoints (or utf-16 or ucs2 encodings of them).

Comment: Note this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512687/sql-server-utf8-howto which implies that if you are using SQL server 2008, you are up a creek.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I'm using SQL Server 2012 (thank god) I've added a bunch of debugging on hibernate to see if it's really breaking where I think its breaking. I flipped back to my Oracle DB to eliminate a few more code paths. I'm zeroing in!