# Why am I getting "SyntaxError: invalid range in character class" when I upgrade to Vue 2.6.0?

Tags: spring-boot, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I've updated my vue to 2.6.0 and I get this error message in my browser console:

```
SyntaxError: invalid range in character class vue.runtime.esm.js:495
2b0e/<     vue.runtime.esm.js:495
2b0e     vue.runtime.esm.js:1
s     bootstrap:78
56d7     ExportTable.vue:1:556
s     bootstrap:78
[0]     bootstrap:151
s     bootstrap:78
n     bootstrap:45
<anonymous>     bootstrap:151
<anonymous>     https://mywebsite.com:8443/js/app.ee42fe22.js:1:2
```

My backend is `Spring Boot`. I'm building the frontend by running `npm run build` and having it copied to the resources folder of my `Spring Boot` set up via the `pom.xml`.

Before upgrading to 2.6.0, I was on 2.5.22 and everything was working great. To try and narrow down the problem, I tried a lot of things that were a waste of time, but what I noticed was that when I deleted the `<style>...</style>` block of the `ExportTable.vue` file that I was getting the error in, the error would no longer come up in `ExportTable.vue` and instead show up in the parent component.

```
<style>
.title-search {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#hiddenDailyLimitFld {
  color: #c21232;
  background-color: #f9dede;
  border: 1px solid #c21232;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-searchLinkBtn {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 35px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.newSearchBtn {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4679b2;
  width: 8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: right;
}
</style>
```

I also tried deleting each css selector block 1 by 1 and building/deploying to production to see if it was a particular css block that was causing it, but the error continued to show up until I deleted all the CSS blocks and the  `<style>...</style>` tags themselves.

The odd thing is that I only get it when I deploy to production with the `npm run build` command. My `package.json` looks like it's running the correct commands according to this block:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

When I use vue-cli3 to "serve" under the task menu, which looks like it runs the command `$ vue-cli-service serve --mode development --dashboard`, there are no errors and everything works fine. I tried deploying to prod with `vue-cli-service build --mode development` and it worked fine so it looks like there seems to be an issue when it gets minified or built for production.

I think this might be related to this issue from 2016:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2291

UPDATE: Here's my `main.js` file:

```
import './plugins/vuetify'
import '@/resources/css/global.css'
import '@/resources/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css'

import Vue from 'vue';

import App from './App';
import Error from '@/view/Error/Error.vue';
import router from './router.js';
import store from './store.js'
import rest from '@/services/RestService.js';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import './resources/js/font-awesome.js'

Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

Vue.config.productionTip = true;
Vue.config.devtools = true;

var vue_opts = { el: '#app', render: h => h(Error) };
rest.check().then((response) => {
  if (response.user) {
    vue_opts.render = h => h(App);
    vue_opts.router = router;
    vue_opts.store = store;
  }
  new Vue(vue_opts);
})
  .catch((res) => {
    new Vue(vue_opts);
  });
```

Comment: are you using `regex` anywhere?

Comment: I am not. at first, I thought it might be that because I saw a post about it, but their error message indicated that it was a regular expression syntax error. And I checked for regex, but no regex.

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade your Spring Boot backend as well?

In my case, having same errormessage, my backend was sending wrong Charset-Header. Starting my jar from Windows resulting in Header windows-1252, from Linux US-ASCII.

I had to set my vertx default charset to UTF-8. In spring [How to set UTF-8 character encoding in Spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163590/how-to-set-utf-8-character-encoding-in-spring-boot) might be your solution?

Otherwise just depending on frontend this https://forum.vuejs.org/t/misplaced-meta-charset-utf-8-fun/55800 might be useful.

Again, in the end I think you are sending wrong encoding to the browser.