# Spring Boot: how to set encoding in JSPF files to UTF-8

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, encoding

I am struggling with encoding of jspf files. When I insert a german umlaut (e.g. "ä") in the jspf the output in the browser is broken (some unreadable character).

I start Spring Boot from within eclipse, the jspf file itself is encoded as UTF-8.

Note that *this issue only applies to jspf files*. With jsp files everything is working fine as they contain the page directive `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>`.

This is what I tried so far (none of them worked):

- Insert `spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8, spring.http.encoding.enabled=true, spring.http.encoding.force=true` in *application.properties*
- Insert `server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8, server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true, server.servlet.encoding.force=true` in *application.properties*
- Use `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` as JVM arg
- Use a [CharacterEncodingFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28214811/9826710)

The only working option is to insert page directive in the jspf file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
```

But this has to be inserted in every jspf file. I'm looking for some global option.

Answer (score 1):

By default the JSPF Encoding its ISO-8859-1, the solution you found is the correct to change the encoding, and as you say could be a pain modify every single file. The ways I know for change that in the easiest way is adding this to your `web.xml`

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
</jsp-property-group>
```

Or change the context of your application server, idk if you are using Tomcat or another one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73799769/9826710) cannot be applied directly to Spring Boot as it doesn't "have" a web.xml.

Instead you have to configure the property group programmatically:

```
@Component
public class JspContextCustomizer implements TomcatContextCustomizer {
  @Override
  public void customize(Context context) {
    JspPropertyGroup group = new JspPropertyGroup();
    group.addUrlPattern("/*");
    group.setPageEncoding("UTF-8");
    context.setJspConfigDescriptor(new JspConfigDescriptorImpl(
      Collections.singletonList(new JspPropertyGroupDescriptorImpl(group)),
      Collections.emptyList()));
  } 
}
```

This works!