# Add a Servlet Filter in a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, annotations, servlet-filters, spring-boot

I'd like to have [ETag suport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-etag). For this purpose there is a `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` which does all the work. How can I add it without declaring it in my `web.xml` (which actually does not exist, because I somehow got by without it so far)?

P.S. I use Spring Boot 1.1.4

P.P.S. Here's a full solution

```java
package cuenation.api;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import java.util.EnumSet;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/cue-categories");
        return registration;
    }

}
```

Comment: Uhm, your question contains a link to the solution. Just scroll down a few lines.

Comment: @zeroflagL Scroll down a few lines where: here or in the spring documentation? I'm not following you!

Comment: @zeroflagL Oh, I see what you mean. But my problem is I don't have any xml configuration whatsoever. See [my custom initializer](https://gist.github.com/dVaffection/259156e18b2ac5660dc2). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot

Comment: how to add ShallowEtagHeaderFilter to the project so that it can evaluate and send Etag to the browser. Do we need to override anything?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### When using Spring Boot

As [mentioned in the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-and-filters), the only step needed is to declare that filter as a Bean in a configuration class, that's it!

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
    return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
  }
}
```

### When using Spring MVC

You're probably already extending a `WebApplicationInitializer`. If not, then you should convert your webapp configuration from a `web.xml` file to a `WebApplicationInitializer` class.

If your context configuration lives in XML file(s), you can create a class that extends `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` - if using configuration classes, `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` is the proper choice.

In any case, you can then add Filter registration:

```
  @Override
  protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] {
      new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
    };
  }
```

Full examples of [code-based Servlet container initialization are available in the Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-container-config).

Comment: No I don't extend `WebApplicationInitializer` neither directly nor indirectly. Actually the only config I have is `application.properties` where I put my mongodb connection string. I tried to extend `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` but it requires to implement me a bunch of methods.

Comment: Ok, I added [my custom initializer](https://gist.github.com/dVaffection/259156e18b2ac5660dc2). But looks like spring does not see it. What did I mess here?

Comment: so you probably have a web.xml file somewhere... it's either web.xml (configuring your webapp with XML) or a WebApplicationInitializer. I'm adding a complete example in my answer.

Comment: No, as I said above I don't have any configuration files other than `application.properties`

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot then?

Comment: Yes, I use spring-boot-starter-web 1.1.4

Comment: I've seen this [17.15 Code-based Servlet container initialization](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-container-config). My frustration comes because they use `dispatcher-config.xml`. I don't know what it is!

Comment: updated my answer - you should have made clear from the start that you're using Spring Boot...

Comment: Hm, I added `WebConfig` class inside my [Application](https://gist.github.com/dVaffection/9c75855adec931be999b) but TomCat does not start saying `Could not instantiate bean class [cuenation.api.Application$WebConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6aed0802]: No default constructor found;`

Comment: Ok, I finally [figured this out](https://gist.github.com/dVaffection/24b127a6cbeae49fb48b)

Comment: Trying your approach spawned a new and different error, which warrants a new posting.  Inserting your code is giving a `No default constructor` error.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36533585/no-default-constructor-when-adding-servlet-filter-in-spring-boot

Comment: Is it same as if we register filters using configure(HttpSecurity http) by addFilterBefore and addFilterAfter methods

Answer (score 3):

A bit late answer.

My solution was to create custom annotation:

```
import org.springframework.core.annotation.AliasFor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

// ...

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Component
public @interface Filter {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Component.class, attribute = "value")
    String value() default "";

}
```

And then simply apply it to the filter implementations:

```
@Filter
public class CustomFilter extends AbstractRequestLoggingFilter {

    @Override
    protected void beforeRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
        logger.debug("before req params:", request.getParameterMap());
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String message) {
        logger.debug("after req params:", request.getParameterMap());
    }
}
```

See more: [`@AliasFor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html), [Spring custom annotations question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123835/spring-requestmapping-for-controllers-that-produce-and-consume-json)