# Add ShallowEtagHeaderFilter in Spring Boot MVC

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-boot, servlet-filters, etag

I'm trying to adjust my application configuration in order to setup ETag support.

I have just checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151057/add-a-servlet-filter-in-a-spring-boot-application/26157610) SO question, so let me say where my code is different from it:

1. I don't use any xml configuration file whatsoever.
2. I'm using different configuration classes for each aspect of the system. My `WebConfig` looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "xxx", "yyy" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Bean
   public Filter shallowETagHeaderFilter() {
        return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
   }
      ...
}
```

3. And my SecurityConfig looks like this:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        ...

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().exceptionHandling()
                        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").authenticated()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/**").authenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable()    
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

    }
```

4. I also have an initializer class, which is empty:

```
    @Order(value=1)
    public class SecurityWebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    }
```

I don't see anywhere the `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` been added to the default chain or anything, how can I use it in this setup?

Comment: And your problem/question is? Spring Boot should add the filter automatically. Your initializer isn't used so that doesn't do nor add anything. Spring Security is already enabled by Spring Boot so your `@EnableWebSecurity` isn't needed.

Comment: Well, it's not setting up it automatically in this case. How can I modify my initializer to start the ShallowEtagHeaderFilter?

Comment: You cannot as the initializer isn't doing anything in a Spring Boot application.

Comment: I'm really not following. So I should not use the initializer?

Comment: Have you read the Spring Boot documentation and looked at the samples? It creates an executable jar/war or needs a custom initializer if you want to deploy it as a war, instead of a executable jar file.

Comment: Read the whole thing once again (http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/), can't sort this out. I got an executable jar. Made my configuration just as shown in the post, still can't use this filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright,

According to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/headers.html) post:

> [...] To help mitigate this Spring Security has added cache control support which will insert the following headers into you response.
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Expires: 0

So, what happened is that ETag support was added, but Spring Security invalidated it in the response. It seems that if you want to use both Spring Security and ETag support, you need to declare the following code line (highlighted by the arrow):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/**").authenticated()
        .and().csrf().disable()    
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenProcessingFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        ===> http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }

}
```