# Spring RequestMapping for controllers that produce and consume JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

With multiple Spring controllers that consume and produce `application/json`, my code is littered with long annotations like:

```java
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Is there a way to produce a "composite/inherited/aggregated" annotation with **default** values for `consumes` and `produces`, such that I could instead write something like:

```java
    @JSONRequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

How do we define something like `@JSONRequestMapping` above?  Notice the `value` and `method` passed in just like in `@RequestMapping`, also good to be able to pass in `consumes` or `produces` if the default isn't suitable.

I need to control what I'm returning.  I want the `produces`/`consumes` annotation-methods so that I get the appropriate `Content-Type` headers.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As of Spring 4.2.x, you can create custom mapping annotations, using `@RequestMapping` as a meta-annotation. So:

> Is there a way to produce a "composite/inherited/aggregated"
>   annotation with default values for consumes and produces, such that I
>   could instead write something like:
>
> ```
> @JSONRequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
> ```

Yes, there is such a way. You can create a meta annotation like following:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @interface JsonRequestMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "method")
    RequestMethod[] method() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "params")
    String[] params() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "headers")
    String[] headers() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "consumes")
    String[] consumes() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "produces")
    String[] produces() default {};
}
```

Then you can use the default settings or even override them as you want:

```
@JsonRequestMapping(method = POST)
public String defaultSettings() {
    return "Default settings";
}

@JsonRequestMapping(value = "/override", method = PUT, produces = "text/plain")
public String overrideSome(@RequestBody String json) {
    return json;
}
```

You can read more about `AliasFor` in spring's [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) and [github wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model).

Comment: This is really interesting; didn't know about this new feature. The [JavaDoc for @AliasFor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AliasFor.html) is really good. And there is also a [wiki page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model) describing in more detail about Spring's annotation model.

Comment: Thank you!  This looks like the information I was looking for. In `public @interface JsonRequestMapping `, is it neccessary to redeclare `name`, `value`, `path`, `method`, `params`, `headers`?  I'm only interested in having defaults for `consumes`, `produces`.

Comment: Yes, if you want to override their corresponding value in `RequestMapping`, you should re-declare them.

Answer (score 41):

The simple answer to your question is that there is no [Annotation-Inheritance in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1624084/953327). However, there is a way to use the Spring annotations in a way that I think will help solve your problem.

[@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) is supported at both the type level and at the method level.

When you put `@RequestMapping` at the type level, most of the attributes are 'inherited' for each method in that class. This is [mentioned](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) in the Spring reference documentation. Look at the [api docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) for details on how each attribute is handled when adding `@RequestMapping` to a type. I've summarized this for each attribute below:

- `name`: Value at Type level is concatenated with value at method level using '#' as a separator.
- `value`: Value at Type level is inherited by method.
- `path`: Value at Type level is inherited by method.
- `method`: Value at Type level is inherited by method.
- `params`: Value at Type level is inherited by method.
- `headers`: Value at Type level is inherited by method.
- `consumes`: Value at Type level is overridden by method.
- `produces`: Value at Type level is overridden by method.

Here is a brief example Controller that showcases how you could use this:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/", 
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public class JsonProducingEndpoint {

    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postAFoo(@RequestBody ThisIsAFoo theFoo) {
        fooService.saveTheFoo(theFoo);
        return "http://myservice.com/foo/1";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/foo/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ThisIsAFoo getAFoo(@PathVariable String id) {
        ThisIsAFoo foo = fooService.getAFoo(id);
        return foo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/foo/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ThisIsAFooXML getAFooXml(@PathVariable String id) {
        ThisIsAFooXML foo = fooService.getAFoo(id);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, Ali Dehghani's answer best answered the question I asked, so I've marked that as accepted.  But I ended up using your suggestion, seemed cleaner in some sense, so I'm giving you a bounty too, (+100, since I can't do +50 twice).  Thanks.

Comment: Question: I have exactly the same scenario as you, but a method returning a string cannot be accepted (415) because it is not JSON. You don't have this problem? The objects are deserialized correctly because we have Jackson and `@Jsonproperty` on the fields of the model.

Comment: @WesternGun not sure I follow. The java method should return a serializable Object, not a String. In my example only the POST method is returning a String because it is returning the location of the created resource. Might be worth opening your own question.

Answer (score 20):

You shouldn't need to configure the consumes or produces attribute at all.  Spring will automatically serve JSON based on the following factors.

- The accepts header of the request is **application/json**
- **@ResponseBody** annotated method
- Jackson library on classpath

You should also follow Wim's suggestion and define your controller with the **@RestController** annotation.  This will save you from annotating each request method with **@ResponseBody**

Another benefit of this approach would be if a client wants XML instead of JSON, they would get it.  They would just need to specify xml in the accepts header.

Comment: Perfect and Absolute match for me. I even removed the consumes and produces

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `@RestController` instead of `@Controller` annotation.

Comment: Actually it is juct combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, so it have nothing in common with Content Type

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 annotations in Spring: **@RequestBody** and **@ResponseBody**. These annotations consumes, respectively produces JSONs. Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-spring).

Comment: That is interesting information, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to control what I'm returning.  I want the `produces`/`consumes` annotation-methods so that I get the appropriate `Content-Type` headers.