# How to set defaults for @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using `@RestController` with `@RequestMapping` annotations to define all of my servlets with `spring-mvc`.

Question: how can I define some defaults for those annotation, so I don't have to repeat the same configuration regarding eg `consumes` and `produces`?

I'd like to always apply the following config, without having to repeat it on each path:

```
@GetMapping(produces = {APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})

@PostMapping(
consumes = {APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
produces = {APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```

Comment: I haven't done spring-mvc in a long time, but can't you just write your own annotation?

Comment: Unfortunately @GetMapping has `@Target(ElementType.METHOD)`, so I cannot just create my own annotation and reuse it. Neither can I add the annotation to class level of my servlet controller. It's not allowed at class level...

Comment: you can apply produces and consumes on RequestMapping on class level.

Comment: I don't want to set `consumes` on `@RequestMapping(method = GET)`! Only on the POST mapping.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123835/spring-requestmapping-for-controllers-that-produce-and-consume-json

Comment: @SangamBelose that looks like the solution. Though it's not very nice having to copy the whole `@GetMapping` annotation class content therefore.

Answer (score 5):

Probably it's easiest to just create a custom `@RestController` annotation and use that on classlevel. Then I only have to repeat the `@PostMapping(consumes...)` mappings:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public @interface DefaultRestController {

}
```

Usage like:

```
@DefaultRestController
public class MyServlet {
         @GetMapping("/getmap") //inherits the 'produces' mapping
         public void getmap() {
         }

         @PostMapping("/postmap", consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
         public void postmap() {
         }
}
```

Better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The target for `RequestMapping` annotation could be either a method or class. It can be used instead of `GetMapping` and `PostMapping` annotations that target only methods.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html

> Specifically, @GetMapping is a composed annotation that acts as a
>   shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET).

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html

> Specifically, @PostMapping is a composed annotation that acts as a
>   shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST).

Assuming your Controller Name is `HelloController`, add the `RequestMapping` annotation with appropriate methods at `Class` level so that it applies automatically to all the paths.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST}, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },)
class HelloController{
}
```

This confgiuration can be overridden by annotating it in individual methods.

Comment: I don't want to set the `consumes` on `GET`! Only on post.

Comment: @membersound - I think this is all you can do. Rest has to be overridden in method level annotations.