# Using custom JSON format in REST

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a REST service exposed using Spring Boot that consumes and produces a JSON. Now I want to customize the JSON messages that will be acepted or produced from my service, like instead of Accepts: application/json I want to specify Accepts: application/x.myCompany.v1+json.

Can anyone suggest me how to proceed with this using spring?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```java
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/x.company.v1+json", 
                produces = "application/x.company.v1+json")
```

Since Spring 4.2, you can create a meta-annotation to avoid repeting yourself:

```java
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RequestMapping(consumes = "application/x.company.v1+json", 
                produces = "application/x.company.v1+json")
public @interface CustomJsonV1RequestMapping {

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "method")
    RequestMethod[] method() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "params")
    String[] params() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "headers")
    String[] headers() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "consumes")
    String[] consumes() default {};

    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "produces")
    String[] produces() default {};
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
@CustomJsonV1RequestMapping(method = GET)
public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195033/1426227) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to define a custom format for `application/x.myCompany.v1+json` and also be able to serve content using default formatting for `application/json` then you would want to define a HttpMessageConverter. There's a guide on this [at baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) and and another at [logicbig](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/custom-http-message-converter.html) or you can see an example of [registering converters](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-service-common/blob/6512495582f0bcbda7f2f4fc5802d6a54a8c059f/activiti-cloud-services-dbp-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/cloud/alfresco/config/AlfrescoWebAutoConfiguration.java#L35) and [implementing the conversion](https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-service-common/tree/99602a6a0bc4e10dd8130426dfdd1c3a8d6bf1bc/activiti-cloud-services-dbp-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/cloud/alfresco/converter/json) to conform to a specific set of content formatting guidelines.