# How to properly configure jackson converters for JSON and plain text

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

For a Spring MVC (not Spring Boot) I've had to change the configuration class that extended `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` and add the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation. This causes problems with the conversion of the responses for several endpoints. The project defaults to `application/json` and it is used for most of the responses however, there are several endpoints which return `application/xml` and even a few that return `text/plain`. JSON responses are modified to remove fields containing `null` using the following Java config:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
  List<MediaType> supportedMediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
  supportedMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
  builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
  builder.timeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(
    builder.build()
  );
  jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedMediaTypes);
  return jsonConverter;
}
```

This causes JSON responses to be returned correctly but results in an exception for the `text/plain` endpoints. They then produce an error:

```
No converter for [class java.lang.String] with preset Content-Type 'null'
```

The error can be resolved by adding the default string converter before the JSON converter:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
  converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
  converters.add(jsonConverter());
}
```

However, this causes a problem specifically for endpoints that return JSON but in Java only have `String` as the return type. A string in between double quotes should be returned: `"response"`, but they only return the string without quotes: `response`. This makes most clients to not recognise the response as valid JSON. Curiously POJOs are still converted to valid JSON.

How can I configure my Spring MVC (not Spring Boot) project using a configuration class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer` and is annotated with `@EnableWebMvc` to return JSON without `null` fields and single strings as valid JSON (e.g. with double quotes: `"response"`) but also plain text?

Comment: You can force it using `consumes` property from `RequestMapping` annotation: [Spring RequestMapping for controllers that produce and consume JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123835/spring-requestmapping-for-controllers-that-produce-and-consume-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable solution has been found to have the REST API return valid JSON responses even for methods which return a string (so with double quotes around the returned string) while also being able to return XML and plain text responses.
In the configuration class that `implements WebMvcConfigurer` and is annotated with `@EnableWebMvc` we register the default converters by overriding the `extendMessageConverters`. The default `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is removed from the list and our custom JSON converter is added instead as the first converter in the list. By adding the JSON converter before the `StringHttpMessageConverter` methods that return a string have their responses converted to valid JSON (with double quotes) while `application/xml` and `text/plain` responses also work properly.

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is add one more bean for handling string responses as you added for json and add the convertor to converters.add(stringConverter());

Comment: Creating a `StringHttpMessageConverter` with supported media types `text/plain` and `application/xml` resolves the problems I have. However, it introduces a new problem, the springdoc `v3/api-docs endpoint which returns JSON gets converted to one big string, making it invalid JSON.

Comment: add the new convertor after json one   converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
  converters.add(jsonConverter());converters.add(stringConverter());

Comment: I've tried that sadly it doesn't work. The order for loading the converters doesn't seem to effect the responses. Adding `application/json` to the supported media types for the string converter also doesn't seem to have any effect. At least not if it's added after `text/plain` and `application/xml`.