# Grails 3 - manipulating web.xml

Tags: grails, web.xml, grails-3.0

As now web.xml will be generated dynamically, I'd need to add a simple filter class at the top of of it without writing or using a plugin.
What code would I need and where should I put it?

Or could I somehow get a template of what grails would generate for a web.xml and I could modify and override it?

I saw in the documentation

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy(file: "grails-app/conf/custom-web.xml",
         tofile: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/web.xml")
}
```

but first: would this function in application.yml?

and second: I'd still need an appropriate web.xml template to change...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From cfrick's suggestion, I tried this, (applies to grails 3)

Create a filter e.g. [grails-project]/src/main/java/hello/SimpleCORSFilter.java
(Create the 'java' directory, or create a SimpleCORSFilter.groovy in the [grails-project/src/main/groovy directory)

You can use the example in [one of the spring guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/).

```
package hello;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
//        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        // I used this instead
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Then in [grails-project]/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy, add the filter, e.g.

```
import hello.SimpleCORSFilter

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    myFilter(SimpleCORSFilter)
}
```

Also, in the grails docs, to order your filter:

```
import hello.SimpleCORSFilter
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean
import org.springframework.core.Ordered

myFilter(FilterRegistrationBean) {
    filter = bean(SimpleCORSFilter)
    urlPatterns = ['/*']
    order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a Filter, but I wasn't able to wire it. It was easier for me to edit web.xml. Zyro pointed me to the same FilterRegistration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28475431/grails-3-0-0-m1-create-plugin-could-not-find-method-bintray

Answer (score 0):

i know it's not the anwers to the actual question, but adding filters "springboot" style is just providing a `@Bean` for it.  E.g. you can just put it in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`.  More details can be found at: [How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

Grails 3 embraces Springboot and with that came the good bye to XML based config (not saying it is forbidden, but its discouraged)

Answer (score -3):

You can use install-templates command, which will copy templates to src/templates directory, there you will find web.xml template inside war directory, you can customize it

See http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html

Comment: thank you, but there is no "install-templates" in Grails 3 any more

Comment: Grails 3 ? which exact version, grails 2.4.4 have it

Comment: 3.0.0.M1, the version which will come next with some breaking changes. That's why it's worth to begin with it ahead of time ;)

Comment: Oh its just preview, no idea how can you overwrite web xml with 3.0

Comment: It wasn't me!!?? And it wasn't me either to upvote my own question!!?? I could click false one time... but not two times... I hope :-/