# Grails 3.0.0.M1 - create-plugin - Could not find method bintray

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-3.0

In the frustration, that I am not able to add a filter and mapping to the gone web.xml I wanted to create a plugin, only to be able to use doWithWebDescriptor()
(My first plugin for my first application)

I am not good enough to discern, if the following is worth a JIRA, or I screwed something again.

Can someone decide this one for me please?
Thank you

```
$ grails create-plugin plug
| Application created at /home/rawi/work/grails/plug
$ cd plug
$ grails --stacktrace
Resolving dependencies. Please wait... | Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find method bintray() for arguments [bintrayPublishing_5hk626f78vi1vldz7smpu61or$_run_closure1@49aaf237] on root project 'plug'. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method bintray() for arguments [bintrayPublishing_5hk626f78vi1vldz7smpu61or$_run_closure1@49aaf237] on root project 'plug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
        at bintrayPublishing_5hk626f78vi1vldz7smpu61or.run(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle:1)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:154)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyScript(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:102)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$000(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$1.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_29ntuuuf8qocv81m54eiznh1n.run(/home/radu/work/grails/plug/build.gradle:28)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:154)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:492)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ClientProvidedBuildAction.run(ClientProvidedBuildAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find method bintray() for arguments [bintrayPublishing_5hk626f78vi1vldz7smpu61or$_run_closure1@49aaf237] on root project 'plug'.
```

Comment: regarding your "first application": you are aware, that grails 3 is not yet finished and M1 does not mean RC1. you maybe make you life harder than needed that way.

Comment: You're right. But I'm somehow confident, that the big boys of the Grails-Team will release it before I think out all my first application ;)

Comment: as long as you are aware, kudos to you for testing it from a new user perspective

Comment: my audacity reveals my be my level of awareness...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that issue is fixed already: https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/commit/caa7cfde2708af799da4b9e29c47531cd2274061

you can get around it for now by either adding the bintray gradle plugin as shown in the linked commit or by commenting out this line in your plugins build.gradle file:

```
apply from:'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/master/profiles/plugin/templates/bintrayPublishing.gradle'
```

regarding your issue with the missing web.xml: you could just use a FilterRegistrationBean. e.g. (grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy):

```
beans = {
    myFilter(FilterRegistrationBean) {
        filter = new MyFilter()
        order = 100
        urlPatterns = ["/my/url/pattern/*"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! - I didn't know about the FilterRegistrationBean in resources.groovy, it is not yet in the grails-3 docs. Where could I learn more about the force of resources.groovy?