# Spring Boot/MVC filters by annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am converting a web application to use spring-boot.
The application currently uses resteasy which I want to convert to use spring-rest/mvc.

It has been really straight forward so far (mainly replacing annotations).
The one place I am having problems has to do with Filters (HTTP Filters).

Currently the application has a Filter that is used in a few of the endpoints.
An annotation is used to specify which rest points the filter is applied to. The annotation is based on @NameBinding

Can this be done with Spring (ie create an annotation and for each rest endpoint method that I want the filter applied I would annotate it)?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a Filter class that extends OncePerRequestFilter and override `shouldNotFilter()` method. You would @Autowire `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to get an associated handler with the incoming request.

Then you can simply check whether that handler method contains the annotation or not.

```
@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerMapping reqMap;

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) reqMap.getHandler(request).getHandler();
    return !method.getMethod().isAnnotationPresent(SomeAnnotation.class);
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
     // filtering logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with spring-boot, you can use FilterRegistrationBean and map it to specific URLS

[How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

http://www.leveluplunch.com/blog/2014/04/01/spring-boot-configure-servlet-mapping-filters/

Comment: yes, but using an annotation on the method seems a lot cleaner. Is there no way to do it using annotations?

Comment: as per this post..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thanks Paul, but the annotation mentioned in the link (@Filter) is used to specify a Filter. What I am looking for is an annotation I would put on rest methods to specify that I want a given Filter to be applied to the specific rest endpoint being annotated. I guess I could create a smart FilterRegistrationBean that inspected annotations and assigned filters accordingly, was just hoping it already existed.

Comment: I did a li'l bit of research..I couldn't find anything that did that off the bat.