# How to add a Filter with WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

With `WebApplicationInitializer`, I can easily add a filter to the `ServletContext` within the `onStartup()` method.

How to add a filter with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`? Do I have to use XML?

### ADD 1

To help others understand the Spring Web Configuration more easily, I draw the following illustration.

Now you just need to first understand the `rational` behind Spring Web configuration. And then pick up which config class to inherit and which method to override from below.

*It's less painful to look it up than to remember so many things.*

[image]

And a good article on Spring Web Initialization:

http://www.kubrynski.com/2014/01/understanding-spring-web-initialization.html

### ADD 2

Based on `Tunaki`'s reply, I checked the `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`. The filter registration happens in the following code:

[image]

Even I override the green `getServletFilters()` method, I still cannot access the `Dyanmic` result of the `registerServletFilter()`. So how can I configure the filter by `addMappingForUrlPatterns()`?

It seems I `have to` override the whole `registerDispatcherServlet()` method.

Comment: The filters are automatically mapped to the `DispatcherServlet`. If you need something else, override the `onStartup` method (don't forget to call the `super.onStartup` and register the filters yourself as you normally would do. That still works...

Comment: Or simply add another class implementing `WebApplicationInitializer`... There can be multiple there doesn't have to be a single one!.

Answer (score 13):

`WebMvcConfigurer` is an interface that is used to customize the Java-based configuration for Spring MVC enabled via `@EnableWebMvc`. `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is just an adapter providing default empty methods for this interface.

It does not configure the `DispatcherServlet`, which is what filters are used by. As such, you can't use `WebMvcConfigurer` to configure servlet filters.

To easily configure filters, you can inherit from [`AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html) and override [`getServletFilters()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#getServletFilters--):

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new CharacterEncodingFilter() };
    }

}
```

If you want to further configure a filter, you will have to override [`onStartup`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.html#onStartup-javax.servlet.ServletContext-) instead:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addFilter("name", CharacterEncodingFilter.class)
                  .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But even by extending `AbstractDispatcherServletInitialier`, how can I get the `FilterRegisteration` object so I can call `addMappingForUrlPatterns()`?

Comment: My Add1 is just for reference. My Add2 is relevant to the question about adding a filter. You can ignore my Add 1.

Comment: AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer also requires createServletApplicationContext, getServletMappings and createRootApplicationContext to be implemented and the filter dont seem to be applied.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the Dyanmic result of the `registerServletFilter()` as follows in your app config (specifically, [WebApplicationInitializer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)):

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    rootContext.register(
        AppConfig.class,
        SecurityConfiguration.class,
        HibernateConfiguration.class 
    );

    // Add cuatom filters to servletContext
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("recaptchaResponseFilter", new RecaptchaResponseFilter());
    filterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    filterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(MVCConfig.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create spring beans that implements Filter and @Inject ServletContext inside of them.
Then in a @PostConstruct method, you can register them with servletContext.addServlet("myFilter",this);

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Inject
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addServlet("myFilter",this);
        filter.addMapping("/myMapping");
    }
}
```

The bean must not be declared in the rootContext that is initialised with ContextLoaderListener(rootContext) because the servlet 3.0 api forbids using dynamic registration for the listeners.
So it must be declared in the dispatcherContext that is given to DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext )

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
     // Create the 'root' Spring application context
     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
       new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
     rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

     // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
     container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

     // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
       new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
     dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

     // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
     ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
       container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
     dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
     dispatcher.addMapping("/");
   }

}
```

[spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html)