# Filter pattern definition doesn't apply

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I defined my `AlanCookieFilter` by `@Bean` annotation:

```
@Bean
    public Filter alanCookieFilter() {
        return new AlanCookieFilter(); // type of AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
    }
```

Then I added my filter by using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Configuration
public class AlanOAuthWebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilter(alanCookieFilter()).antMatcher("/**");
    }   
}
```

But when I started application, I got following log message:

```
o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'alanCookieFilter' to: [/*]
```

It seems that `AlanCookieFilter` is still mapped to `/*` instead of `/**`. I'm totally confused by this wield behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the filter twice. First time as a Servlet [`Filter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html?is-external=true) and second time in the [filter chain](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-chain-proxy) of Spring Security.

By default Spring Boot maps your filter to `/*`, see [Spring Boot Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-and-filters):

> By default, if the context contains only a single Servlet it will be mapped to `/`. In the case of multiple Servlets beans the bean name will be used as a path prefix. Filters will map to `/*`.
>
> If convention-based mapping is not flexible enough you can use the `ServletRegistrationBean` and `FilterRegistrationBean` classes for complete control. You can also register items directly if your bean implements the `ServletContextInitializer` interface.

To change the mapping, see also: [How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

You should only add Spring Security filters (or extentions) to the filter chain, see [HttpSecurity.html#addFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#addFilter(javax.servlet.Filter)):

> Adds a Filter that must be an instance of or extend one of the Filters provided within the Security framework.

Your filter extends `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and should be added only to the filter chain.

One way to stop Spring Boot to map your filter is: Don't expose your filter with `@Bean`, see [Spring Boot Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-and-filters).

> When using an embedded servlet container you can register Servlets and Filters directly as Spring beans.