# How to tell SpringBootApplication to load web.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am moving from legacy project to spring boot project,
The legacy project uses some self-defined servlets in `web.xml`, along with `resin` to provide http service.
We wish that by using SpringBoot, together with the embedded `tomcat`, we could generate a `jar` file and start that jar file to provide http services.
I was trying to move everything inside `web.xml` to a `WebXmlConfig.java`, but I find out some problems which are hard to handle, so my problem is that how to tell Spring Boot to load `web.xml`?
I have searched some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699422/spring-boot-application-to-start-application-initializing-servlets-in-web-xml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225549/dispatcherservlet-and-web-xml-in-spring-boot/55701504#55701504), but they all seem not working, so any idea I can do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't. As Spring bOot isn't loading that thing that is Tomcat (assuming you use the default). Also loading that will lead to other issues with Spring Boot. So your best option is to solve those issues you have (which shouldn't be that hard).

Comment: @M.Deinum Seems like everyone is suggesting so, lol