# Spring Boot - Download WSDL using ?WSDL

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot

I created a webservice using Spring Boot using the steps defined [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)When I try to download the wsdl , I am having to use .wsdl in the url. However when I use ?wsdl , the wsdl is not getting downloaded. How can I rewrite the url to download the wsdl when I use ?wsdl in the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this filter to be able to acces wsdl with Spring styled `.wsdl` as well as `?wsdl`:

```
public class WsdRequestCompatibilityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if ("GET".equals(request.getMethod()) && "wsdl".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getQueryString())) {
            request.getSession().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(request.getRequestURI() + ".wsdl").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to register this as been named `wsdlRequestCompatibilityFilter` and add folowing config to your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>wsdlRequestCompatibilityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>wsdlRequestCompatibilityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Is there a way to do it using annotations in Spring ?

Comment: No, Im afraid it is not configurable.

Comment: You can code this in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30658752/1705830