# Spring web Project - how to enable a simple filter?

Tags: java, spring, filter

Trying to add a very simple filter to my Spring-web-project, I've noticed that *all examples are using the web.xml file that is not available when choosing a web project on Spring.

Could someone write a complete starter set for a super simple filter?
just printing here in all filter states is enough.
I'll pick it up from there to checking session data.

any help/good reference is welcomed.
thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, do you use plain Spring or Spring Boot?

Comment: Dependency spring-boot.

Comment: There are about 10 answers there, without a verified answer. each solving in a different way, could you point out to any of the specific answers?
I cannot seem to get the complete picture of the relevant setting.

Comment: All of the solutions work, they are just different way of solving the problem. I prefer the FilterRegistrationBean method of registering filters. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to create a filter in your Spring Boot application.
See the following question for multiple options: [How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

I prefer creating a FilterRegistrationBean in my application context, it can have similar configuration then the config you would write to web.xml using plain Spring MVC.

From the above question registering a filter can be done as follows:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

   FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
   registration.setFilter(someFilter());
   registration.addUrlPatterns("/url/*");
   registration.addInitParameter("paramName", "paramValue");
   registration.setName("someFilter");
   registration.setOrder(1);
   return registration;
} 

public Filter someFilter() {
   return new SomeFilter();
}
```

If you need multiple filters, just create a bean for each.

Spring Boot will automatically find these beans, and configure the filters for you.