# Spring Boot Rest API filter not invoked

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, filter, spring-restcontroller

I want to implement filter on my Spring Boot Rest API project but some how my filter not invoked. I have added below implementation for that.

```
public class AutorizationFilter implements Filter{
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AutorizationFilter.class);
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    log.info("**** Start ****");

}
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info("**** doFilter ****");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);

}
@Override
public void destroy() {
    log.info("**** end ****");
}}
```

**init** and **destroy** method are working but **doFilter** method not invoke.

```
@Configuration
public class RestApiConfig {
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<AutorizationFilter> filterRegistrationBean(){
    FilterRegistrationBean<AutorizationFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new AutorizationFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/**");
    return registrationBean;    
}}
```

My controller is as below:

```
@RestController 
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Object> hello() {
    Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    resultMap.put("data","called home controller");
return new ResponseEntity<>(resultMap,HttpStatus.OK);
 }
}
```

Any one please help me why **dofilter** method is not working.

Comment: you just created a BEAN with filter, but did't apply it to application.
Common thing is to use Spring security ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter``` and add filters inside. For more info use http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Comment: @Mykhailo Voloshyn:  So I can't use filter without Spring security?

Comment: I suppose you can. But i don't have such experiance. Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot

Comment: finally i found the solution, I need to replace registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/**") with registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*") and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @PiyushChaudhari add your solution as an answer and accept it to help future readers. I had the same problem but almost didn't notice your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

finally i found the solution, I need to replace `registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/**")` with `registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*")` and it's working fine for me.