# Filters initialization in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets, servlet-filters

I'm pretty new to Spring and I want to migrate some old Spring 4 project to Spring Boot 2.X. I'm facing the issue with the filters initialization. In the current approach I have something like this:

```
public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() { return new Class[]{ Configuration1.class, Configuration2.class, Configuration3.class};}

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() { return null; }

   @Override
   @NonNull
   protected String[] getServletMappings() { return new String[]{"/"}; }

   @Override
   public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      super.onStartup(servletContext);

      //MY FILTERS
      FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
      corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
      corsFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
      //.... more filters there
   }
```

As I understand it was done like this because of bean initialization occurs later than `onStartup` method (not sure though, correct me if I'm wrong).

I copy-pasted filters initialization logic to `onStartup()` of `ServletContextInitializer` class when migrating the app to spring boot. Unfortunately, I'm facing such issue right now when trying  to access dispatcher and forward request further:

```
public final class MyFilter implements Filter { 
    @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
       //some logic
       String servlet = filterConfig.getInitParameter("servlet");
       RequestDispatcher rd = servletContext.getNamedDispatcher(servlet); // null pointer here :(
       rd.forward(new RESTPathServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
    }
```

My questions are as follow:

1. What's the proper approach of using filters in spring boot?
2. Why `onStartup` in `ServletContextInitializer` have different flow then `onStartup` in `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` (looks like beans are initialized early on)
3. Is there any way to simulate `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` logic using `ServletContextInitializer` as my local runner.

Comment: [Start from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825946/how-to-add-a-filter-class-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Declare the filters as beans using `@Bean` methods, if you need further customizations add an `FilterRegistrationBean` as well. 2. Because Spring Boot controls the container as well it needs early init, 3. just declare them as beans, don't try to outsmart the framework.