# Extending GenericFilterBean vs Implementing Filter error while tomcat startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I was trying out logging requestIds for every request using the following tutorial: https://oddblogger.com/spring-boot-mdc-logging

My actual aim is to inject data into log4j2 MDC, and consequently, I write the following Filter:

```java
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper;

public class RequestFilter implements Filter
{
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    try
    {
      String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      MDC.put("requestId", uuid);
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
      ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(
          httpServletResponse
      );
      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, responseWrapper);
      responseWrapper.setHeader("requestId", uuid);
      responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
    }
    finally
    {
      MDC.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Due to reasons, I create an application WAR file, and deploy it on Tomcat 8.5
This deployment fails, with cryptic errors to me like:

```
4-Nov-2022 10:34:33.941 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
04-Nov-2022 10:34:33.941 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/Application] startup failed due to previous errors
PreDestroy invoked...
04-Nov-2022 10:34:34.005 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Application] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.abc.Class$1] (value [com.abc.Class$1@6a28aaa3]) and a value of type [com.abc.String] (value ["Random"]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
04-Nov-2022 10:34:34.005 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Application] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.abc.Class$1] (value [com.abc.Class$1@6f649cfe]) and a value of type [com.abc.String] (value ["RANDOM"]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
04-Nov-2022 10:34:34.005 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [Application] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@36663d16]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@19b4f4cb]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
[2022-11-04 10:34:34,014] Artifact Application.war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
04-Nov-2022 10:34:34.782 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.58/webapps/manager]
04-Nov-2022 10:34:34.816 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5.58/webapps/manager] has finished in [35] ms
04-Nov-2022 10:34:37.547 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1378)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

After much googling due to the cryptic error, I managed to figure out that I instead have to extend the Spring provided `GenericFilterBean` class. I changed it, and the application now works correctly.

What's incorrect with implementing the `Filter` provided in the `javax` package, and why does the Container throw out the above weird error in such case?

I used Spring Boot 2.7.5 if it matters.

Comment: Actually implementing it, is no problem. You just need to correctly "wire" it.. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter ..so there's no *need* to extend/use "generic filter bean", just few (dis-?/) advantages... https://stackoverflow.com/q/19825946/592355 , https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html

Comment: @xerx593 I have tried the above, both with the Component and without. GenericFilterBean works without the annotation, but implementing Filter doesn't work in either case