# Bad encoding with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, utf-8, tomcat8

I have a Tomcat 8 that fetches data from MySQL. The rows in MySQL are encoded good (like texts in Russian). If I debug the server, the selected rows are in good encoding. However, the returned JSON has bad chars.
I checked my `server.xml` and I have:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Notice that I have `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in there.

What else can I do?

Comment: Have you configured any servlet filters for encoding? Consider using `org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504732/how-to-use-org-springframework-web-filter-characterencodingfilter-to-correct-cha

Comment: Adding the filter helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

URI encoding applies just to the URI as far as I know; it does not affect the encoding of whatever you're sending back. You should set the proper response headers, something like "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8".

Here's a snippet of a Spring Boot app that I'm working on, it's for the request but it might give you an idea of what you need:

```
private RestTemplate rest = new TestRestTemplate() {{ getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))); }};
private HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders() {{ setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); }};
```

If you could show your code maybe we could better help you.

Comment: I don't understard, How do I use getMessageConverters? just using requestHeaders  doesn't help.
How do I set proper response headers?
And my code is very simple. Up until the return statement everything is good.